# Storing oracle query results into bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, unix, solaris

```
declare -a result=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -silent  $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD@$DB << EOF $SQLPLUSOPTIONS $roam_query exit; EOF`
```

I am trying to pull data from an oracle database and populate a bash variable. The select query works however it returns multiple rows and those rows are returned as a long continuous string. I want to capture each row from the database in an array index for example:

```
index[0] = row 1 information
index[1] = row 2 information
```

Please help. All suggestions are appreciated. I checked all documentation without no luck. Thank you. I am using solaris unix

Comment: Stack overflow was not allowing me to enter the `` but I know they are supposed to be there so that is not the issue.

Comment: You are assigning the entire result to the *first* element of the array. A first pass at doing what you want would be `declare -a results=( $($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus ...) )`.

Comment: That has its own risks, though, as it subjects the result to word-splitting and pathname expansion. (Most importantly, you'll probably end up with one array entry per *field* per row, not just one entry per row.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have bash version 4, you can use the `readarray -t` command to do this. Any vaguely recent linux should have bash v4, but I don't know about Solaris.

BTW, I'd also recommend putting double-quotes around variable references (e.g. `"$DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD@$DB"` instead of just `$DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD@$DB`) (except in here-documents), using `$( )` instead of backticks, and using lower- or mixed-case variable names (there are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and if you use one of those by accident, weird things can happen).

I'm not sure I have the here-document (the SQL commands) right, but here's roughly how I'd do it:

```
readarray -t result < <("$oracle_home/bin/sqlplus" -silent  "$dbuser/$dbpassword@$db" << EOF
$sqlplusoptions $roam_query
exit;
EOF
)
```